# react-native can't run correctly in android

Tags: android, react-native

I had trouble running react-native project in an android virtual device.
When I make a react-native project with `react-native init MyTest` and then`react-native run-android`,but it shows a "red screen" in the AVD with a tips " 'View' has no propType for native prop 'RCTView.elevation' of native type 'number' ".
Has anyone come across this issue? How can I do to solve this problem?[here is the Snapshot of the "red screen"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tItqz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Got rid of it by upgrading react-native to the latest version (0.16.0, not the RC).